# How to efficiently return the Roads within a radius

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, latitude-longitude

I have an ArrayList of Road Object where it has atttributes such as number,start_latitude,start_longitude,end_latitude,end_longitude. Now I want to return the  roads which falls in a radius of 500m for a given lat long value. So I tried with

```
ArrayList<Roads> RoadList=new ArrayList<Roads>();

//I added all the road objects like below
RoadList.setNumber(01);
RoadList.setStartLatitude(1.24);
RoadList.setStartLongitude(102.3);
RoadList.setEndLatitude();
RoadList.setEndLongitude();

//Then I compute the distance between the end of road and given lat lon and also distance between  start of road from give lat lon values and if the distance is below 500 I pick the road object.
given latitude=1.2;
given logitude=103.8
public ArrayList<Integer> getRoads(){ 
ArrayList<Integer> roads=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0; i<RoadList.size();i++){

double x=  Math.pow( Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getStartLatitude()-given latitude,2)+Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getStartLongitude()-given longitude,2),0.5);
double y=  Math.pow( Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getEndLatitude()-given latitude,2)+Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getEndLongitude()-given longitude,2),0.5);


if(x <500 || y<500){
  roads.add(RoadList.get(i).getNumber());
}

}
return roads;
}
```

Since my ArrayList Is a bit large it takes a while.So is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is your array sorted in any way? If not, you are going to have to visit every element in the array no matter what, giving you O(n)  runtime. However, if it is sorted, you could get that much lower as you won't have to process all the roads.

Comment: Sorting is expensive too, generally O(n log(n)) which is more expensive than this single pass over the array. It might be worth it, if it saves time elsewhere.

Comment: Hi there, 
I'm assuming that each road is a linear segment with no twists or turns etc.  If you have more complex roads with corners etc then you may have to divide the road into road segments.  
Then, borrow a page out of the Book from game developers and use line-segment to circle distance checking algorithms. See:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078309/distance-between-a-circle-and-a-line-segment

Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about converting these two lines

```
double x=  Math.pow( Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getStartLatitude()-given latitude,2)+Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getStartLongitude()-given longitude,2),0.5);
double y=  Math.pow( Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getEndLatitude()-given latitude,2)+Math.pow(RoadList.get(i).getEndLongitude()-given longitude,2),0.5);
```

into something like this

```
double start_x1 = RoadList.get(i).getStartLatitude()-given latitude;
double start_x2 = RoadList.get(i).getStartLongitude()-given longitude;
start_x1 *= start_x1;
start_x2 *= start_x2;

double end_x1 = RoadList.get(i).getEndLatitude()-given latitude;
double end_x2 = RoadList.get(i).getEndLongitude()-given longitude;
end_x1 *= end_x1;
end_x2 *= end_x2;

double x = Math.sqrt(start_x1 + start_x2);
double y = Math.sqrt(end_x1 + end_x2);
```

So instead of using Math.pow for squaring, you can perform this calculation in O(1), may be it improves our speed.

I am not completely sure about it but you can try it out and let me know.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, it won't improve speed.  `Math.pow` checks whether the exponent is 2, and if so, it just does the multiplication.  To apply the distance formula, by far the best way is with `Math.hypot`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a spatial index for region objects, such as quadtree, R-Tree or PH-Tree.

You can insert the road segments as rectangles (chose the rectangles such that a road-segments is the diagonal of the rectangle).
Then you can perform a window-query with a query window of your search point +/- 500m. This will return all rectangles (road-segments) that intersect with the query window.
As last step you would have to check all returned segment weather they really are inside the given radius, because the query window is rectangular and will likely return segments that are a bit too far away.

Java implementations of various spatial indexes can be found [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) and [here](http://www.ph-tree.org).